# Database tables are not visible in Android Pie 9

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite, android-9.0-pie

I have tested my app (with an sqlite databse) on a Android 9.0 Pie phone, when I opened the data base in DB sqlite browser, it was not showing the tables that I created in my Sqlite databse. I did the same on emulator of Android 9.0 Pie within Android Studio... but database tables are not visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is probably that you have only copied the database file and not the **-wal** and **-shm** files. **Try copying all three files and the tables will then probably be available.**

- The -wal and -shm files have the same name as the database file but suffixed with -wal and -shm respectively.

The reason is that with Android Pie on, the default mode is [WAL (write-ahead logging)](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) as opposed to journal mode that was the previous default mode.

With **journal** mode changes are written to the database and also stored in the journal file allowing changes to be rolled back from the journal file.

With **WAL** mode the changes are written to the -wal file (which is effectively part of the database), a rollback effectively deletes the changes from the -wal file. However, if the -wal file has not been commited to the actual database and the database is opened without the -wal file then the changes will appear to have been lost.

If the database is fully closed this will checkpoint and include the changes in the -wal file to the database file.

- You could force the use of journal mode by using the SQliteDatabase method [**disableWriteAheadLogging()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#disableWriteAheadLogging()). If using a subclass of [SQLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper) then this can be issued by overriding the [**onConfigure**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#onConfigure(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)) method.
- However, this does supress the advantages of **WAL** mode.